# Resource consumption on running Deadlock profiler against production database

Tags: monitoring, sql-server

It is well known that 
running a profiler consumes a lot of resources depending on what events are being monitored.

I am interested in monitoring deadlocks that occurs occasionally (3~5 a week). 
using SQL Server profiler with following event selections (every event but highlighted ones from `TSQL_Locks` template)

[image]

Would it slow down to monitor(for one whole week without stopping) only locks against production databases?

Are there any rules of thumb on
**when** and **how long** to run the profiler for deadlocks?

Comment: Don't monitor for Lock:Deadlock Chain because it happens quite often (eahc time the server walks a chain of locks to detect if deadlocks are present, ie. every few seconds). I would only monitor for the Deadlock Graph event and nothing else, on server side trace as Nick already suggested.

Comment: @Remus: Thank you for the tip. As I was reading about `Lock:Deadlock Chain` on BOL, it doesn't looks like I'd need to monitor it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a server side trace instead.  Do a search for using Profiler to create server side traces to figure out the details.

Here is a decent [blog post](http://sqlchicken.com/2009/07/how-to-create-a-server-side-trace-with-sql-profiler/) on the topic.  This is the best way to reduce the impact on your production db.

Your other alternative is to turn on trace flags 1204 and/or 1222 & monitor the output in the errorlog.

How long should you run the trace for? Long enough to figure out & fix the code involved.  You'll also want to run the trace again once the fix has been put in place to make sure its not re-occurring.

There maybe some that argue its always wise to have the trace flags enabled.  I think it depends on the application, as trace flags also create additional load.

Comment: Thanks, Nick.  Running a server-side trace seems like a good idea for my situation.